# BroadcastTransaction not registered, Corda

Tags: corda

that when BroadcastTransaction is called the following error is raised:

```
Party C=GB,L=London,O=Controller rejected session request: 
    class ee.ut.cs.examples.parking.flows.BroadcastTransaction is not registered
```

Here is my FlowLogic that wants to call BroadcastTransaction

```
package ee.ut.cs.examples.parking.flows

import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable
import net.corda.core.contracts.Command
import net.corda.core.contracts.StateAndContract
import net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow
import net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic
import net.corda.core.flows.StartableByRPC
import net.corda.core.identity.Party
import net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction
import net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder
import ee.ut.cs.examples.parking.contracts.ParkingSpaceContract
import ee.ut.cs.examples.parking.structures.ParkingSpace

@StartableByRPC
class CreateParkingSpace(private val dayRate: Double, private val nightRate: Double) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val notary: Party = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first()

        val parkingSpace = ParkingSpace(owner = ourIdentity, dayRate = dayRate, nightRate = nightRate)
        val createCommand = Command(ParkingSpaceContract.Commands.Create(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey))
        val outputState = StateAndContract(parkingSpace, ParkingSpaceContract.CONTRACT_REF)

        val utx = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary).withItems(outputState, createCommand)

        val stx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(utx)
        val ftx = subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx))

        subFlow(BroadcastTransaction(ftx))

        return ftx
    }


}
```

Here is BroadcastTransaction:

```
import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable
import net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic
import net.corda.core.flows.InitiatingFlow
import net.corda.core.flows.SendTransactionFlow
import net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction

/**
 * Filters out any notary identities and removes our identity, then broadcasts the [SignedTransaction] to all the
 * remaining identities.
 */
@InitiatingFlow
class BroadcastTransaction(val stx: SignedTransaction) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // Get a list of all identities from the network map cache.
        val everyone = serviceHub.networkMapCache.allNodes.flatMap { it.legalIdentities }

        // Filter out the notary identities and remove our identity.
        val everyoneButMeAndNotary = everyone.filter { serviceHub.networkMapCache.isNotary(it).not() } - ourIdentity

        // Create a session for each remaining party.
        val sessions = everyoneButMeAndNotary.map { initiateFlow(it) }

        // Send the transaction to all the remaining parties.
        sessions.forEach { subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(it, stx)) }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `SessionRejectException`.

This is being thrown because the node receiving a message from `BroadcastTransaction` does not have a flow registered to respond to `BroadcastTransaction`.

You need to install a responder flow on the receiving node of the form:

```
@InitiatedBy(BroadcastTransaction::class)
class Responder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // TODO: Flow logic here.
    }
}
```